# Como utilizar emailJS.com cuando se monta un componente en react usando useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

queria saber si me pueden ayudar con este codigo.
Contexto: estoy haciendo mi primer porfolio y la idea es usar la libreria emailJS.com para que me llegue un correo a mi gmail cuando alguien entre a ver el deploy del mismo, para tener un 'rastreador' y monitorear las vistas a mi perfil.
El problema es el siguiente:
Yo no quiero que el usuario que entra a mi pagina llene ningún formulario lo que quiero lograr es que el correo se envia directamente cuando se monte el componente App usando useEffect().Este es mi codigo completo:

```
const App = () => {
  const form = useRef();

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        "service_fwmu3vq",
        "template_dqufk4h",
        form.current,
        "A-0VQcem-nMbwDjM6"
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
  };
  useEffect(sendEmail, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
        
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Especificamente el problema es que en la funcion que me brinda la documentacion oficial de Email.js hace refercia como tercer parametro a un formulario **form.current**, ese tercer parametro lo intente sacar o directamente poner undefined pero no logro hacer que funcione.

```
const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        "service_fu3vq",
        "template_dqk4h",
        form.current,
        "A-0VQcem-nMDjM6"
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
  };
```

Espero haber sido clara con mi pregunta,si pudieran darme alguna sugerencia de como solucionarlo estaría muy agradecida!! <3

Comment: `form.current` no existe porque no tenes un elemento `form` al que le agregas la prop `ref={form}`. Además no se si ese useEffect te va a funcionar, creo que la forma correcta seria `useEffect(() => { sendEmail() }, []);`. Tal vez deberias crear un form, ocultarlo con CSS y cargar ahi los datos que necesitas, si es que necesitas algun dato.

Comment: mm si podria ser graciasss!!

Comment: si funciono jajaj  le mando una etiqueta form pelada y me lo toma como parámetro, gracias de nuevo!!